# Ubuntu Terminal Freezes Commands Cannot Execute Until a Reboot

Tags: command-line, reboot

Running Any command for instance `sudo service network-manager restart` seems just stays idle when i press enter key. I have to reboot to restore the machine. What must i do to stop my terminal from freezing.

Comment: check your memory!

Comment: i have 4GB RAM, and 5GB swap. I think it is enough.

Comment: Use `free -h` to check and didn't specs!

Comment: `sudo` asks for your password. Did you enter it?

Comment: sudo never asked for the password. the terminal cannot run any command i type.

Comment: Did you install any fancy bash configuration like prompt themes or such?

Comment: no fancy bash configurations or themes installed

Comment: This is weird.   What happens if you type one of the bash built-ins: does `help` freeze it too?  P.S. Don't reboot: just close the terminal with the red "X".

Comment: in normal state the echo command displays the string it got

Comment: yes i do not reboot, everything stays fine, except i cannot use any terminals. yet i may need to run some commands. its not an easy decision to come to but i always do a reboot.

Comment: So you say after you pressed "enter" after entering a command, "nothing" happens? What happens if you press ctrl-c? Can you switch to another terminal using ctrl-alt-f4?

Comment: ctrl+c does nothing but show ^C, yes i can switch to another terminal with that, but still no commands can work.

Comment: If you boot into recovery mode, can you enter commands there?

Comment: all works fine except at a point in time i cease to execute any commands

Comment: You say it works for a while (how long?) and then the issue comes up?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the log info, you should open another terminal and run the following command:

```
 journalctl -u NetworkManager
```

To check what's happening with the command execution.

You could also try to add an & to the end of the command you're executing to release the command prompt. If you have prompt but can type anything, try running **reset**.

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl+Alt+F(1 or 2 or 3) login there and run some command. If its working fine. Something wrong with gnome-terminal. Try to run following command for any updates are stuck in between.

dpkg --configure -a

apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

apt-get install terminator

terminator is alternate terminal. This having lot of cool features